# jQuery: toggling attribute within a toggleClass function

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, toggle

I'm trying to add an attribute to a searchfield *only when it is visible*, so I have the following code to a) hide the search form initially, b) toggle the visibility and c) add or remove the attribute "autofocus" to the form's input when the form is given the class "focus" (e.g being visible). The code for a) and b) works as it should, c) is my imagined take on how the addAttr() thing should be, but I don't really know Javascript so obviously it's not working. The question is: How do I make it work?

```
$("#searchwdgt").hide();
    $(function() {
        $('#show_search').click(function() {
            $('#show_search').toggleClass('active');
            $('#searchwdgt').toggleClass('focus').slideToggle(400);
            if($('#searchwdgt.focus')) {
                $('#searchwdgt input').addAttr('autofocus');
            } else {
                $('#searchwdgt input').removeAttr('autofocus');
            }
            return false;
        });
});
```

The basic construct is simple. #show_search is an anchor that the user clicks to get the search form (#searchwdgt). To minimize the number of user clicks it would be nice if the attribute "autofocus" could be added to the input (has class "searchfield", is type "search", just for clarification) when the form becomes visible, but for UX purposes it can't be in place always (this messes with tab browsing since the form is hidden initially). So, any constructive pointers that can help solve the issue are most welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the function should be

```
.attr('autofocus','autofocus')
```

instead of

```
.addAttr('autofocus');
```

The reason it isn't working is that each attribute needs to have a value, even if it's null

Comment: Got it. autofocus gets added properly now, thank you. However, I can't get it to remove the autofocus attribute when the form doesn't have class "focus" (e.g isn't visible), at least not with my crappy code (else... removeAttr().) Suggestions?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with the autofocus property? Because (i assume) the autofocus property is only used when the document loads to tell the browser to automatically "jump" to that field after the page had loaded.

if you're trying to get the user to focus on that element, simply use jQuery's .focus() function.

Comment: Basically i'm after the same effect that you see here when you click the Add Comment link - the textarea that appears when doing that is autofocused. It's a small thing but it "feels" helpful. What I want is for the search field to be autoselected when it becomes visible rather than the user having to click into it in order to use it (you click on the show_search link to do a search so there is already intent). I didn't know about focus() - will read and test. Thanks.